# How to get current value of a input via AJAX

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to code some sort of e-commerce website. I'm using Laravel.

I need to get an input's new value if it changes. It is on the cart page and users can change the quantity of the product.

```
 @foreach($order->getBasket as $o)
     <tr>
        <td class="d-flex align-items-center font-weight-bolder">
            <div class="symbol symbol-60 flex-shrink-0 mr-4 bg-light">
                <div class="symbol-label" style="background-image:url('https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/black-logistics-icons/256/Add_product_arrow.png')"></div>
            </div>
            <span>{{$o->getOrder->name}}</span>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center align-middle justify-content-center">
            <div class="form-group align-items-center">
                 <input type="number" step="1" class="form-control form-control-danger w-50 text-center" name="quantity[]" value="1" >
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="text-right align-middle font-weight-bolder font-size-h5">{{$o->price}}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

I want to catch the input's value which is named "quantity[]".

Comment: Welcome to SO  and good luck learning. Show us what have you tried and where you are running into problems. The objective here is for you to do the basic research and show your attempts to solve your own issue and others here help debug that code when it's not working as expected

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I searched before asking here but i couldn't find even where to start. So i couldn't try anything.I thought maybe someone can show me a way.

Comment: Start from reading about [.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event .

Comment: Look for tutorials on how to use events and tutorials on forms and ajax

Comment: Thank you all guys for help! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Names are not required on form elements for ajax, only id's. Below is how to get the value of a form element in javascript using jQuery. If you don't use jQuery this is easily adaptable to native js.

Example HTML

```
 <input type="number" step="1" value="1" id="mynumber">
 <input type="submit" id="submit" value="ADD PRODUCT">
```

Example jQuery (with AJAX)

```
 // Detect click on submit
 $(document).on('click', '#submit', function() {
     // Set variable equal to value of a form element
     var mynumber = $("#mynumber").val();
     // If value is empty do nothing
     if (mynumber == "") {
         return false;
         // If value is not empty continue
     } else {
         // Start AJAX
         $.ajax({
             // Set url to your PHP file
             url: "myserverfile.php",
             // Form data is being posted
             method: "POST",
             // Form data is the defined variable
             data: {
                 mynumber: mynumber
             },
             // Data is text
             dataType: "text",
             // If success start a function
             success: function(data) {
                 // Example: send new data to a div
                 $('#mydiv').html(data);
                 // Or do something else of your choice
             }
         });
     }
 });
```

The link below shows the code working, just click the console bar at the bottom of the white viewing window in js fiddle to see the number submitted after you press submit.
https://jsfiddle.net/ge8hz32t/

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. But i need a bit diffrent solution. I have cart page that includes producst and their quantities. For example 1 candy 5$ and 1 chocolate 3$ and total 8$. When user change quantity of chocolate and make it 2 for example, i want to change the cost of chocolate to 6$ and total cost to 11$ without refreshing page. I think i need AJAX for this.

Comment: Yes, in that case AJAX is required but you can still use the code I provided along with AJAX to send the values to a PHP file where your changes can be processed. I'll edit the post and add an AJAX example to it.

Comment: I've edited my post with an example of using AJAX. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. But i couldn't understand how to get value (var mynumber = $("#mynumber").val();) in my controller.
i set url to;
url: "ProcessController.php",
or i tried full directory
url: "app/Http/Controllers/Process/ProcessController.php",
but i couldn't get the value in controller

Comment: In your PHP file you retrieve the variable using its name: $mynumber=$_POST['mynumber'];

Comment: Thank you again but i get "undefined index" error. You can see screenshot of error [here](https://ibb.co/KmBGZV6)

Comment: I forgot to mention my example uses jQuery version 3.4.1 (this will matter) are you using jQuery and if so what version?

Comment: I use 3.5.1 version of jQuery

Comment: Ah. A few things have been updated in that version and it breaks quite a lot of the functionality. I haven't yet upgraded mine so I don't know how to help there.